# wait()/waitpid() returns 1, not pid of child, how to fix that?

Tags: c, parent-child, wait, pid

this is a follow up to [How to squeeze in additional parameters to a reaper function when a parent is signalled to kill a child (c)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399801/how-to-squeeze-in-additional-parameters-to-a-reaper-function-when-a-parent-is-sig)

In my reaper(), I try to obtain the child's pid the parent is about to finish (non-brutal word here). but wait() does not return the pid of the child; instead, it returns 1. I can't find a doc for return value of 1 anywhere. Any heads up?

```
void    reaper(int sig)
{
    int status, killedpid;

    while(killedpid = (/*waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)*/wait(&status)) >= 0)
    {
        printf("reaper %d killed %d\n", getpid(), killedpid);
    }
}
```

My results:

```
reaper 5933 killed 1 //actual child pid is 5936
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Oh, I say go ahead with the terminology. That's part of the fun of *nix. "The child died, and the parent reaped the zombie process."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the classic **assignment in conditional** error - the expression is evaluated as following (because comparison has higher [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) then assignment):

```
if ( killedpid = ( wait( &status ) >= 0 )) { ...
```

The `killedpid` will get a value of TRUE, which is `1` in C. To get around this use parenthesis and **compile with high warning levels** like `-Wall -pedantic`:

```
if (( killedpid = wait( ... )) >= 0 ) { ...
```

Comment: The same applies to PHP. I used `pcntl_waitpid()` and had the same error causing the return value to always appear as `1`.